# How can I show the height of the tcolorbox?

Tags: tcolorbox, dimensions, height, measure

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tcolorbox}
   Bla

   Bla
   \begin{tcolorbox}
   Bla

   Bla
   \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

How can we do this?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The skin `draft` can be used to print box dimensions while you are working in its design:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tcolorbox}[draft]
   Bla

   Bla
   \begin{tcolorbox}[draft]
   Bla

   Bla
   \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You could access the height of the blocks by putting them in a box and measure the height of this box. With the `printlen` package this length can be printed in your unit of choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newsavebox{\bigbox}
\newsavebox{\smallbox}
\usepackage{printlen}

\begin{document}

\savebox{\bigbox}{%
   \begin{tcolorbox}
   Bla

   Bla
   \begin{tcolorbox}
   Bla

   Bla
   \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{tcolorbox}
}

\savebox{\smallbox}{%
   \begin{tcolorbox}
   Bla

   Bla
   \end{tcolorbox}
}

\usebox{\bigbox}   

\uselengthunit{cm}
\printlength{\ht\bigbox}  

\printlength{\ht\smallbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's good working.